# OCMock observer mock pattern for NotificationCenter vs partial mock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

OCMock has a [special way](http://ocmock.org/reference/#observer-mocks) to mock/spy NSNotificationCenter. You can use it to see if a given notification was posted like this:

```
id observerMock = OCMObserverMock();
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addMockObserver:observerMock name:@"MyNotificationEventNameHere" object:nil];
OCMExpect([observerMock notificationWithName:@"MyNotificationEventNameHere" object:OCMOCK_ANY]);
// Do something to cause the notification to fire here
OCMVerifyAll(observerMock);
```

Alternatively, you could also use a partial mock to accomplish the same thing like this:

```
id notificationCenterSpy = OCMPartialMock(NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter);
// Do something to cause the notification to fire here
OCMVerify([notificationCenterSpy postNotificationName:@"MyNotificationEventNameHere" object:OCMOCK_ANY]);
```

Question is why should I prefer OCMock's Observer Mock pattern vs the Partial Mock pattern for notification center verification?